# Iterate an object on a specific order

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have some JSON like this:

```
{ 
"a": { "text": "text", "index": 5 },
"b": { "text": "text", "index": 3 },
"c": { "text": "text", "index": 1 },
}
```

Now I need to interate this object and call a function on every property of the first level (a, b and c), but I have to do it on order using the "index" property, like "c" first, then "b" and last "a".

However I read that I shouldn't use a for in loop:

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order (see the delete operator for more on why one cannot depend on the seeming orderliness of iteration, at least in a cross-browser setting).

then how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a copy, sort it and _then_ operate on it?  Or you're hoping to do this without a copy?  I can imagine doing it with a `while` loop, but that seems onerous...

Comment: Yes, I think making a copy would be acceptable

Comment: A copy would be a bit inelegant and unnecessary though - just use the native array methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could,

1. Get the properties of the object as an array using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
2. Sort the properties of the object using [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
3. Use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through the sorted items (which is executed in ascending order of the array).

```js
var items = {
  "a": {
    "text": "text",
    "index": 5
  },
  "b": {
    "text": "text",
    "index": 3
  },
  "c": {
    "text": "text",
    "index": 1,
  }
};

Object.keys(items).sort(function(a, b) {
  return items[a].index - items[b].index;
}).forEach(doStuff);

function doStuff(key) {
  console.log(items[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

```js
let obj = { 
  "a": { "text": "text", "index": 5 },
  "b": { "text": "text", "index": 3 },
  "c": { "text": "text", "index": 1 }
};

function test(p) { 
    console.log(p);
}

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
      .reverse() 
      .forEach(function(p){
         test(obj[p]);
      });
```

Comment: It does iterate from a - b - c, but how to reverse or sort the iteration?

Comment: @StefansArya getOwnPropertyNames returns an array. Simply call reverse() on that. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Covert the object to an array with elements in sorted order based on the index.
2. Than simply forEach() on the sorted properties.

Sort function can be implemented as :

```js
var obj = { 
"a": { "text": "text", "index": 5 },
"b": { "text": "text", "index": 3 },
"c": { "text": "text", "index": 1},
}

 function sortProperties(obj, sortedBy, isNumericSort, reverse) {
            sortedBy = sortedBy || 1; // by default first key
            isNumericSort = isNumericSort || false; // by default text sort
            reverse = reverse || false; // by default no reverse

            var reversed = (reverse) ? -1 : 1;

            var sortable = [];
            for (var key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    sortable.push([key, obj[key]]);
                }
            }
            if (isNumericSort)
                sortable.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return reversed * (a[1][sortedBy] - b[1][sortedBy]);
                });
            else
                sortable.sort(function (a, b) {
                    var x = a[1][sortedBy].toLowerCase(),
                        y = b[1][sortedBy].toLowerCase();
                    return x < y ? reversed * -1 : x > y ? reversed : 0;
                });
            return sortable; // array in format [ [ key1, val1 ], [ key2, val2 ], ... ]
        }
        
        sortProperties(obj, 'index', true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The another solution is store the object keys and reverse it, then iterate with the object keys.

```js
var obj = { 
 "a": { "text": "text", "index": 5 },
 "b": { "text": "text", "index": 3 },
 "c": { "text": "text", "index": 1 }
};
var yourFunction = console.log;
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.reverse();
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
 yourFunction(obj[keys[i]]);
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to sort the data. Just reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also make use of `reverse()` method of javascript if you want to access the json items in reverse order.
get the array of all the keys of json using `Object.keys()`
reverse the array using `reverse()` method
and finally you can make use of javascript `forEach()` method to work on the items of the json. Sample code is shown below

```
let obj = {
"a": { "text": "text", "index": 5 },
"b": { "text": "text", "index": 3 },
"c": { "text": "text", "index": 1 },
}

Object.keys(obj)
            .reverse()
            .forEach(ele => {
              console.log(obj[ele]);
            });
```

visit **[This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)** to know more about `reverse()` method

Answer (score -1):

Probably you should use `Object.keys` to get a list of all the properties, sort that list, then iterate over it.

Comment: @connexo one could even argue it is one

Comment: @connexo Take it to Meta.  Is my answer incorrect?  I actually did expect the site to say "converting trivial answer to a comment".